# How to force HTML5 geolocation to fail?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I've been writing an app that uses the geolocation API heavily. How can I test how my app handles all the failure cases? What is the easiest way to force the various types of failures?

I'm using Firefox, but can use a different browser if necessary.

By "easiest", I mean quick and simple ways to test this, preferably that won't require me to install whole new browsers.

Comment: Disconnecting your PC from the internet could be a option ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus, that isn't very doable for an automated test, though. It also only causes one kind of failure. I want to test all the types of failure (the geolocation API has a separate callback for failure that it passes the reason to).

Comment: To the downvoter, care to comment why this is a bad question?

Comment: my comment was just a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer has location simulation settings in their developers tools (F12). You can simulate a custom location by lat/lon, GPS available or not available, and GPS available with no signal.

Comment: Bah, this isn't ideal (can't be automated, in particular), but it seems to be the only solution at this time.